# Check box do banco com mysql e php

Tags: php, mysql

Como criar automaticamente check box com dados vindos de uma tabela no banco?

Comment: Faça um while/foreach e dentro dele crie os checkbox com os respectivos id, values e descrições. Você já tem algum código feito, pode colocar ele na pergunta?

Comment: Ainda não fiz o código mas vou fazer e assim que terminar.

Comment: Precisa fornecer mais detalhes, está usando o PDO ou MySQLi para conectar no banco? qual informação o checkbox deve ter? tem a consulta feita? adicione esses detalhes na pergunta.

Comment: acabei de fazer aqui reaproveitando codigos anteriores e deu certo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php 
    $result_categorias = "SELECT * FROM categoria";
    $result_categorias = mysqli_query($conn,    $result_categorias);
    while($row_categorias = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_categorias)){ 
?>
<input type="checkbox" name"categoria" value="<?php echo $row_categorias['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row_categorias['nome']; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
```